# google cloud vision OCR wrong translation

Tags: google-cloud-vision

How to prevent google cloud vision from translate to other languages that not specified

in my case some Arabic characters translated to Persian while read the text

I use Language Hints but it's not solve the issue

imageContext.LanguageHints.Add("ar");

Example
کبير

Arabic ك بير <- كبير

Persian ک بير <- کبير

My code:

```
var client = Google.Cloud.Vision.V1.ImageAnnotatorClient.Create(); 
var image = Image.FromFile(imgPath); 
ImageContext imageContext = new ImageContext(); 
imageContext.LanguageHints.Add("ar"); 
TextAnnotation text = client.DetectDocumentText(image, imageContext); 
Result= $"Text: {text.Text}";
```

Comment: Do you want to extract an Arabic text from an image? Or do you want to extract the text and perform some translation to it ? This tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/ocr#detect_text_in_a_remote_image) shows how to extract the text image and use `languagehints` to specify the language in the `request.json`. Can you follow this tutorial?

Comment: Yes I have extracted the text but some characters automatically translated to another language(Persian ) which not specified on LanguageHints because it have the same shape

Comment: Not the first  Arabic - Persian issue with google https://support.google.com/google-ads/thread/63061673?hl=en
 i'm not sure there something todo if you already put the language hint

Comment: @OfftDev, have you specified the `languagehints` within the `request.json` file? Also, are you using the code provided [here](languagehints)? Because It does not call the the Translation API.

Comment: I use c#  so the definition of LanguageHints looks like 

imageContext.LanguageHints.Add("ar");

as in documentation it should translate to the specified language only but its translate to another language depending on character shape

Comment: What is the language in your image? Could you share your code ?

Comment: the language in image is Arabic ,   

`
            var client = Google.Cloud.Vision.V1.ImageAnnotatorClient.Create();
            var image = Image.FromFile(imgPath);

            ImageContext imageContext = new ImageContext();
            imageContext.LanguageHints.Add("ar");

            TextAnnotation text = client.DetectDocumentText(image, imageContext);

            lblResult.Text += $"Text: {text.Text}" + "\n";
`,

Comment: @OfftDev, could you edit the question and add your code there? If the text in you image is Arabic, you can follow [this tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/ocr#detect_text_in_a_remote_image) and use its code to detect the language. Have you tried it?

Comment: In addition you can use this code [here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/tutorials/ocr#translating_text) in which you would need to set the `target_language` to Arabic(ar). Did it work for you?

Answer (score 0):

As per this [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/129593350), Cloud Vision does not respect language_hints, it is just a hint not a restriction.

The only way out is to use tesseract, assuming it supports your language. Here is an example for English, you will have to modify it for your language.

```
import string
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
import pytesseract


def unicodeToAscii(uText):
    if uText.isascii():
        return uText
    
    img = Image.new('RGB', (1000, 300), color='white')
    d = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
    fnt = ImageFont.truetype('/Library/Fonts/Arial.ttf', 25)
    d.text((10,10), uText, font=fnt, fill='black')

    tConfig = f"-c tessedit_char_whitelist={string.digits}{string.ascii_lowercase}"
    asciiStr = pytesseract.image_to_string(img, config=tConfig).strip()
    if not asciiStr:
        print(f'Empty: {uText}')
    return asciiStr
```

```
>>> unicodeToAscii('dępartment')
'department'
```