# Google cloud vision DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION language hints - how i can make force use only one language?

Tags: c#, ocr, google-cloud-vision

I work with text recognition on documents. Library for .NET Core

```
var client = ImageAnnotatorClient.Create();
                ImageContext context = new ImageContext();
                foreach (var hints in context.LanguageHints)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("hint " + hints);
                }
               var response = client.DetectDocumentText(fromBytes, context);
```

In Russian there is a phrase "Однажды вечером"(One evening)

[image]

If I use Google DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION without language hints, then I get the result "ОДНАЖДЫ BELEPOM" (First word correct! Second - fail)

Okay, maybe it doubts the language, we will indicate clearly that it is Russian

```
  context.LanguageHints.Add("ru");
  var response = client.DetectDocumentText(fromBytes, context);
```

The result is the same - the second word is entirely in Latin.

I think, somehow I am asking a hint wrong? Let's try other languages ​​for examples

```
context.LanguageHints.Add("en");
  var response = client.DetectDocumentText(fromBytes, context);
```

result:

```
DAHAYKALI BELEPOM
```

As we can see, the hints functionality works by itself, it's just that the Russian word "ВЕЧЕРОМ"(On Evening) is recognized with such low confidence that fallback to used in English OCR.

The question is - how do you force disable all OCR module, except only one language?(russian in this case)  Let him at least try to recognize Russian letters, albeit with less confidence.

Answer (score 0):

Compare your request to the one in the [API](https://cloud.google.com/vision) , in the api you receive the correct value. "Однажды вечером"
(scroll down you have the request json)

Answer (score 0):

As per this [link](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/129593350) it is not possible to restrict the language, it is only a hint.

The solution, not sure if it will work, is to use tesseract with a restricted characters set and run this text through it. https://stackoverflow.com/a/70345684/14980950.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30584832)

Comment: "use tesseract with a restricted characters set and run this text through it." this is the essential part of the answer.